# PWA with location-triggered push notifications?

Tags: push-notification, geolocation, service-worker

I've read that we can use Geolocation and Location-Triggered events to send push notifications to users, to - as an example - [send a discount cupom when he/she is walking near a store](https://econsultancy.com/blog/67418-what-is-location-based-advertising-why-is-it-the-next-big-thing).

For all I could research, this is only possible using native technology. Is that right? Could I achieve today this same result by making a Progressive Web App with web push notifications? Can the service worker "wake up" based on the user current location?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called **Geofencing**. There is [a proposal](https://w3c.github.io/geofencing-api/) for adding it to the Web, but the discussion has stalled and no vendor seems to be interested any longer. See the page at [What Web Can Do Today](https://whatwebcando.today/geofencing.html) for more info.